# Throttling concurrent async requests with loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await, semaphore

I am currently working on making a large amount of requests to a web API. I have tried to `async` this process so that I can do so in a reasonable amount of time, however I am unable to throttle the connections so that I don't send more than `10` requests/second. I am using a semaphore for the throttling but I am not entirely sure how it will work in this context as I have a nested loop.

I am essentially getting a list of models, and each model has a list of days inside it. I need to make a request for each day inside the models. The amount of days can be anywhere from `1` to about `50`, `99%` of the time it's only going to be `1`. So I want to `async` each model because there will be about `3000` of them, but I want to `async` the days in the case that there are multiple days that need to be completed. I need to stay at or under `10` requests/second so I thought the best way to do so would be to set a request limit of 10 on the entire operation. Is there a place that I can put a semaphore that will limit connections to the entire chain?

Each individual request also has to make two requests for `2` different pieces of data and this API does not support any sort of batching right now.

I am sort of new to c#, very new to `async` and very new to `WebRequests/HttpClient` so any help is appreciated. I tried to add all relevant code here. If you need anything else let me know.

```
public static async Task GetWeatherDataAsync(List<Model> models)
{
    SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
    var taskList = new List<Task<ComparisonModel>>();

    foreach (var x in models)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        taskList.Add(CompDaysAsync(x));
    }

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}

public static async Task<Models> CompDaysAsync(Model model)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
                Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token","xxxxxxxx");
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    var taskList = new List<Task<Models.DateTemp>>();

    foreach (var item in model.list)
    {
        taskList.Add(WeatherAPI.GetResponseForDayAsync(item, 
            httpClient, Latitude, Longitude));
    }
    httpClient.Dispose();
    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }

    return model;
}

public static async Task<DateTemp> GetResponseForDayAsync(DateTemp date, HttpClient httpClient, decimal? Latitude, decimal? Longitude)
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(request1);
    StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(response);
    string responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
    double[] data = new double[2];
    if (responseData != "[[null, null]]")
    {
        data = Array.ConvertAll(responseData.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(','), double.Parse);
    }
    else { data = null; };

    double precipData = 0;
    var response2 = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(request2);
    StreamReader myStreamReader2 = new StreamReader(response2);
    string responseData2 = myStreamReader2.ReadToEnd();
    if (responseData2 != null && responseData2 != "[null]" && responseData2 != "[0.0]")
    {
        precipData = double.Parse(responseData2.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""));
    }
    date.Precip = precipData;

    if (data != null)
    {
        date.minTemp = data[0];
        date.maxTemp = data[1];
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: I've done something like this before simply using `Parallel.ForEach`. The overload that takes `ParallelOptions` let's you set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, but you'll need to flatten the days in each model first with `Enumerable.SelectMany`.

Comment: So if I SelectMany my collection, then i'll get a big list of all my days without a relation to the models themselves though, won't I? Does it innately relate them or do I need to do something special to ensure that?

Comment: There's an overload of `SelectMany` that allows you to specify a result selector to project information from both the parent object and the element into a new object. The `Linq` syntax makes an easier job of it. Remember, `Parallel.ForEach` let's you run actions (or tasks) asynchronously and you can still `await` them to complete in every iteration.

Comment: It appears that this implementation of `Parallel.ForEachAsync` would be better suited to `await` your `async` methods. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you completely don't understand what does `SemaphoreSlim` do.

1. Your semaphore is a method-level based local variable, so **every** `GetWeatherDataAsync` method call will spawn `10` calls to your API, without waiting for other client.
2. Moreover, your code will deadlock, if `models.Count > 10`, because you waiting for semaphore in each iteration, those requests are being stacked, and for `11th` your thread will hang forever, as you aren't releasing semaphore:

   ```
   var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10);

   foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(0, 15))
   {
       // will stop after 9
       await semaphore.WaitAsync();
       Console.WriteLine(item);
   }
   ```

What you really need to do is move the semaphore to instance-level (or even type-level with `static` keyword), and wait for it **inside** `GetWeatherDataAsync`, and put `Release` in `finally` block.

As for `Parallel.Foreach` - you should not use it in this scenario, as it's not aware of `async` methods (it was introduced before `async/await`), and your methods doesn't look like they are CPU-bound.

Comment: Your point about the use of `Parallel.ForEach` is misguided. How does a Framework library somehow depend on a C# language feature before it can be useful?

Comment: I mean that Parallel Foreach does not work well with async methods, as it's not using the async lambdas and simply marks method as completed after it's first return.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. So you won't be able to `await` inside every iteration.

Comment: Instance-level as in accepted as a param into the instance of the class?

Comment: This depends on your code. If you create one instance per request, you need a type-level semaphore.

Comment: The examples I posted above are static. I could make them instance methods. I would only need one instance for all requests I believe. I see no reason to create multiple instances. So in this case it would be a safe bet to create one semaphore at instance level and ship it to my instance and then use it in my method, and this would prevent any concurrent connections in this method from reaching 11+?

Comment: In youe sample code `semaphore` is a **local** instance, which means that it will be created separately for each thread. Move it out as a `static` variable, if you need that, then wait for it inside your `GetWeatherDataAsync`. Right now your semaphore simply doesn't work at all.